# How to properly render tables in Rmarkdown HTML documents

Tags: r, knitr

Beginner R user here. When I use Knitr to make a HTML document, the tables are displayed in the same way as they are when I run the R code from an R script, instead of how it looks when I run it from the R notebook. It looks like image1, instead of image2
[image: image1: HTML document]
[image: image2: Run from the R Notebook]
How can I get it to display the tables "properly"? If that can't be done, is there a way to change the non-breaking space characters (&nbsp ;) into "normal" spaces (" ")?

Here is my code

```
set.seed(42)
library(magrittr)
library(qwraps2)
library(markdown)
library(knitr)

# define the markup language we are working in.
# options(qwraps2_markup = "latex") is also supported.
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")

data(mtcars)

mtcars2 <-
  dplyr::mutate(mtcars,
                cyl_factor = factor(cyl,
                                    levels = c(6, 4, 8),
                                    labels = paste(c(6, 4, 8), "cylinders")),
                cyl_character = paste(cyl, "cylinders"))

our_summary1 <-
  list("Miles Per Gallon" =
       list("min" = ~ min(.data$mpg),
            "max" = ~ max(.data$mpg),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$mpg)),
       "Displacement" =
       list("min" = ~ min(.data$disp),
            "median" = ~ median(.data$disp),
            "max" = ~ max(.data$disp),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$disp)),
       "Weight (1000 lbs)" =
       list("min" = ~ min(.data$wt),
            "max" = ~ max(.data$wt),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$wt)),
       "Forward Gears" =
       list("Three" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$gear == 3),
            "Four"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$gear == 4),
            "Five"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$gear == 5))
       )

whole <- summary_table(mtcars2, our_summary1)
whole
```

R-version and loaded packages, in case that can be helpful in spotting errors I've made:

```
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.3                         
year           2020                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        77875                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock        
 [1] "markdown"  "devtools"  "usethis"   "rmarkdown" "knitr"     "qwraps2"  
 [7] "magrittr"  "haven"     "forcats"   "stringr"   "dplyr"     "purrr"    
[13] "readr"     "tidyr"     "tibble"    "ggplot2"   "tidyverse" "rstatix"
```

Comment: You want to use `kable` and optionnally `kableExtra`. Those can be used in R Markdown for proper table rendering. 
Read here: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much, @Jrm_FRL. When I called "kable(table)" instead of just "table", the output was knitted perfectly.